# Angularjs retrieve ng-repeat adjacent to button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not sure how to phrase my question, what I am trying to do is to get the value selected from the button into my controller and loop it to match something

This is how it look like

[image]

My HTML :

```
  <h4 ng-repeat="healthTheme in health">
  {{healthTheme.THEMENAME}} <a href="">Download</a>
  </h4>
```

What I want is when user click on download, it will get the respective name next to it and pass it into the controller so that I can download the data set for it.

Comment: use `<a href="" ng-click="downloadFunc(healthTheme)">Download</a>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the same name in the `ng-click` like:

```
 <h4 ng-repeat="healthTheme in health">
  {{healthTheme.THEMENAME}} <a href="" ng-click="download(healthTheme.THEMENAME)">Download</a>
  </h4>
```

Passing `healthTheme.THEMENAME` inside the `ng-click` will pass the respective name when rendering the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: and of course you should implement the `download(arg){}` method in your controller.

Comment: @HangulSR glad to help